# Are by and from interchangeable here?

Tags: british-english, spoken-english

1)

> That gesture by him was so nice.

2)

> That gesture from him was so nice.

If not then which one is grammatically correct.

Comment: 3) His gesture was so nice.

Comment: What about the first one?

Comment: I think it would be misleading to say one is better.

Comment: Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: The question title asks "Which one is correct and sounds good?"

Comment: Ok I have changed it

Comment: Are they interchangeable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prepositions are tricky beasts. Both your examples are grammatical and natural and mean the same thing **in this specific context**.

But, in general,"by" and "from" are not interchangeable. "By" frequently indicates agency whereas "from" frequently indicates direction. You would not say **by top to bottom** as an idiomatic substitute for **from top to bottom.** And **The clown was shot from the cannon** means something completely different from **The clown was shot by a cannon.**

Going back to your example. Although both forms will likely be interpreted by most as meaning the exact same thing, there may be a slight difference in intended meaning. **By him** simply indicates that he made the nice gesture. **From him** may indicate that the gesture was nice because he was the one who made it. Personally, I think that is too much weight to place on a mere preposition and do not believe that distinction, if intended, would ccommonly be recognized.